# Rails, How to Combine two queries and then user a third query to subtract values from the first to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, dictionary

I have something like so:

```
@users_x = returns 0 or more records with (id, user_id, etc...)
@users_y = returns 0 or more records with (id, user_id, etc...)
@users_z = returns 0 or more records with (id, user_id, etc...)
```

What I'm interested is user_ids. I want to obtain a list of user_id's for @users_x + @user_y while maintaining the order. And then take the user_ids in @users_z and subtract that from the combined list (x+y). In the end getting a list of user_ids.

How can I pull this off w ruby + rails? Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

(@users_x.collect(&:user_id) + @users_y.collect(&:user_id)) - @users_z.collect(&:user_id)

should do the trick. You might want to toss a uniq in there if you don't want there to be duplicates if an id occurs in both @users_x and @users_y

Comment: Thanks! How would I make this uniq? Also, are you sure the orders are being preserved?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the orders are not being preserved which I need. I just tried and the combined result is orders numerically and not with users_x on top of users_y etc...

Comment: This just concatenates the two arrays - the first part will have the ids in exactly the order that they were in in `@users_x`, the second part will contains those from `@users_y`. You can make things unique by calling `uniq`

Comment: Oh interesting, what happens is I'm then running a User.find(suggested_user_ids) which queries in the right order: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IN (8613, 8614, 8615, 8616, 8617, 8618, 8619, 8620, 8621, 7591, 8424, 8423, 8422, 8421, 8420, 8419, 8418, 8417, 8416, 8415) -- For some reason rails is sorting not by the IN order? Any way to make rails return the order based on the IN?

Comment: That's normal - using an `IN` clause doesn't dictate the sort order. You can either resort in ruby or do `ORDER BY FIELD(id, 8621, 7591,8424,...)`